# Elemantary OS Touchpad not Working on Lenovo Ideapad 330s?

Tags: release-juno, touchpad

Elemantary OS Touchpad is not working on Lenovo Ideapad 330s.

I tried `libinput` and synaptics installation an configuration but it did not work.

Comment: Are you getting any error messages when installing libinput and synaptics?

Comment: can you elaborate on what you did and installed when you said "I tried `libinput` and synaptics installation"

Comment: I found anything helpful but before I just saw a post saying downgrade or upgrade the kernel will work but I just lost the link.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this?

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

ref: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031940/how-to-switch-from-libinput-to-synaptics-in-ubuntu-18-04

---

Also you could check the part where you should check if you have two touchpads in the following link:

https://www.dell.com/support/article/cl/en/clbsdt1/sln308258/precision-xps-ubuntu-general-touchpad-mouse-issue-fix?lang=en

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this will help, but have you tried to change the touchpad to basic in the bios. this worked for me on a different os.

Answer (score 0):

I have an IdeaPad S145 and I think it's possible that the touchpad be the same.
This post worked for me.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1227972/touchpad-of-lenovo-ideapad-s145-15iil-not-detected-in-18-04-and-19-10-ubuntu-an

```
The workaround is to pass these parameters to the kernel.

i8042.nopnp=1 pci=nocrs

It's recommended to test before change definitely like this.
```

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters

Good luck.